# Regras na criação de lista em python

Tags: python, lista

Boa tarde,

Preciso cumprir algumas regras na hora de gerar minha lista.

São estas:

1.Ter pelo menos um valor repetido

2.Ter pelo menos 6 valores únicos

3.Não podem se repetir todos os número

Como posso fazer isto??

#### Segue o código

```
import numpy as np
import statistics as st
import random

def lista_random():
    lista = random.sample(range(0, 50), 12)
    lista.sort()
    return lista

lista = lista_random()
print('A sua lista é: ', lista)
print('A média dos índices é: {:.4f} '.format(np.mean(lista)))
print('A moda é: {:.4f} '.format(st.mode(lista)))
print('A Mediana é: {:.4f} '.format(st.median(lista)))
print('A variância amostral é: {:.4f}'.format(st.pvariance(lista)))
print('O desvio padrão amostral é: {:.4f}'.format(st.stdev(lista)))
print('O coeficiente de variação é: {:.4f}'.format(st.variance(lista)))
```

Comment: Coloque um exemplo de uma tentativa real de como abordou o problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu so nao entendi essa pergunta: "3.Não podem se repetir todos os número". Mas testa o codigo pra ver se e o resultado que voce deseja.

```
from random import randint
import numpy as np
import statistics as st
lista = []
while len(lista) < 7:
    num = randint(1, 10)
    if num not in lista:
        lista.append(num)
while len(lista) < 8:
    num = randint(1, 10)
    if num == lista[-1]:
        lista.append(num)

print(f'A sua lista é: {lista}')
print(f'A média dos índices é: {np.mean(lista):.4f} ')
print(f'A moda é: {st.mode(lista):.4f} ')
print(f'A Mediana é: {st.median(lista):.4f} ')
print(f'A variância amostral é: {st.pvariance(lista):.4f}')
print(f'O desvio padrão amostral é: {st.stdev(lista):.4f}')
print(f'O coeficiente de variação é: {st.variance(lista):.4f}')
```

Comment: Acho que ele quis dizer que nenhum número se repete.

Comment: Ah sim. verdade, agora compreendi. Entao esse codigo resolve o problema dele.

Comment: Então o código encaixou perfeitamente porém eu fiz uns ajustes, pois preciso de 12 números na lista sendo que 2 ou mais tem que se repetir, troquei o valor do primeiro while pra 11 e o range de número aleatórios de 1 até 50

Answer (score 0):

A função rendom.simple não vai gerar um número repetido...
então já quebraria sua primeira condição.

```
import random

def lista_random():
    lista = []
    for i in range(0,12):
        lista.append(random.randint(0,50))
    lista.sort()
    return lista

def gerar_lista():
    lista = lista_random()
    print(lista)
    pelo_menos_um_igual = False
    quant_unicos = 0
    for aux in lista:
        repetidos = lista.count(aux)
        print(repetidos)
        if repetidos == len(lista):
            return False
        elif repetidos > 1:
            pelo_menos_um_igual = True
        elif repetidos == 1:
            quant_unicos = quant_unicos + 1
    print(f"Unicos {quant_unicos}")
    if pelo_menos_um_igual and quant_unicos >= 6:
        return True
    return False

while not gerar_lista():
    pass
```

tente esse códico acima, tá bem desorganizado, então se funcionar você pode organiza-lo.

Comment: lembrando que esse código só vai printar a lista com as condições, você pode modificá-lo para salvar em uma variável.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random


def containDuplicate(listOfElements: list) -> bool:
    if len(listOfElements) == len(set(listOfElements)):
        return False
    else:
        return True

def lista_random():
    while not containDuplicate(lista) or len(set(lista)) < 6 and len(set(lista)) == 1:
        lista[random.randrange(1, 50) for i in range(12)]
    return sorted(lista)
```

O `set`serve pra trazer valores únicos da lista. O `len(set())` conta o número de valores únicos na sua lista. Usei estes 2 métodos pra criar uma função que verifica se existem valores únicos na lista.

Basta agregar tudo em um condicional `while` pra ele repetir enquanto as condições não forem satisfeitas.